# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'similarity'

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

```
ws = {}
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
data = 'Some long text'
train_corpus = nlp(data)
train_corpus = [token.text for token in train_corpus if not token.is_stop and len(token) > 4]
test_corpus = nlp('Some short sentence')   
ae = train_corpus.similarity(test_corpus)
```

I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'similarity'` at `ae = train_corpus.similarity(test_corpus)`. If I remove `train_corpus = [token.text for token in train_corpus if not token.is_stop and len(token) > 4]`, it works, yet with stopwords.

How do I remove the stopwords for it to still work?

EDIT: `ae = nlp(train_corpus).similarity(test_corpus)` leads to `TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list)`.

Comment: Why are you using the list comprehension for `train_corpus` there?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: `train_corpus = [token.text for token in train_corpus if not token.is_stop and len(token) > 4]` This line, you're creating `train_corpus` as a list. Why? Clearly `list` doesn't have a `similarity` function. So why are you creating a list here? And what is it that you were expecting this variable to be.

Comment: How do you remove stop words from an nlp object?

Comment: Not like that quite clearly. Check what object `nlp(data)` returns. I'm guessing that object must have the `similarity` function. You need to modify that object, instead of turning it into a list.

Comment: - You are using model of The German Language and putting there English sentences
- if you want to do similarity for phrases not for tokens just you need to glue it back to a string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that you are using german model for english phrases. In your case you would need to glue back the remaining tokens and create a "spacy object" again. In your case you remove all the tokens by this condition len(token) > 4 anyway..

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
# nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
ws = {}
#data = 'Some long text'
data = 'Some long text Elephant'
train_corpus = nlp(data)
train_corpus = nlp(" ".join([token.text for token in train_corpus if not token.is_stop and len(token) > 4]))
test_corpus = nlp('Some short sentence')
ae = train_corpus.similarity(test_corpus)

print(ae)
```